# Which upstart jobs are optional/unnecessary that I can eliminate by renaming from xx.conf to xx.skip

Tags: upstart

I know HOW to have an upstart job not start (mv cron.conf cron.skip).

WHICH upstart jobs are OPTIONAL or UNNECESSARY and still have my system function.
I DO NOT NEED cron, encription, bluetooth, datebase server, print spooler, even my logs; what else can I eliminate?

Or if you like which upstart jobs (daemons) MUST I have running on a gui 
desktop system.

Comment: You shouldn't move the `.conf` file, but create a `.override` file containing `manual`.

Answer (score 1):

"Must run" depend on you needs. For example, I consider `cron` a must-have because otherwise I will not have log file rotation. And periodic updates check.

But if you don't even want logs, and plan to check updates manually, your case is different.

So basically the only correct answer is **"it depends"**. Depends on how you want your system behave and on your use case.

Try to disable services one by one (see @muru comment though --- do not rename the upstart files, add a file with `.override` extension with just the `manual` command in it) and see if the system works for you. Or ask specifically what a service is doing (after researching a bit) and which are the effects of disabling it.

BTW, before doing it, be sure to know how to undo things without a graphic interface using recovery mode; the basics are well explained in [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)